# How to replace text only if surrounded by white space in php

Tags: php, forms, replace, find, translation

I'm trying to create a form that users can submit and use to find and replace text in a long string. However, many of the strings I'm replacing are only 2-3 letters (e.g. "od", "ph") that are often found in the middle of words. I'd want to through all the phrases I'm searching for and only replace them if there is white space before the string to avoid replacing strings that are in the middle of words. Any ideas?

```
if(isset($_POST["text"]))
{
    $original = $_POST["text"];
    $abbreviation= array();
    $abbreviation[0] = 'od';
    $abbreviation[1] = 'rn';        
    $abbreviation[2] = 'ph';
    $abbreviation[3] = 'real';  
    $translated= array();
    $translated[0] ='odometer';
    $translated[1] ='run';
    $translated[2] ='pinhole';
    $translated[3] ='fake';
    $newtext=  str_ireplace ($abbreviation, $translated ,$original);
    echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($newnote));
}
```

Comment: This is something `regex` can address. Please add the `regex` tag to your post to get the right eyes on your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat the abbreviation as a separate word using a word boundary assertion (`\b`) on both sides:

```
preg_replace('/\bod\b/i', 'odometer', 'od test od test od.')
// "odometer test odometer test odometer."
```

If you strictly want to match only when there's whitespace surrounding the the string, use a lookbehind assertion (`(?<=`) and lookahead assertion (`(?=`) matching whitespace (`\s`):

```
preg_replace('/(^|(?<=\s))od((?=\s)|$)/i', 'odometer', 'od test od test od.')
// "odometer test odometer test od."
```

Note how the trailing period is treated differently. (Also note, `preg_replace` can take multiple pattern/replacement mappings as arrays.)

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php):

> A word boundary is a position in the subject string where the current
>   character and the previous character do not both match \w or \W (i.e.
>   one matches \w and the other matches \W), or the start or end of the
>   string if the first or last character matches \w, respectively.

`\w` and `\W` refer to "word" and "non-word" characters:

> A "word" character is any letter or digit or the underscore character,
>   that is, any character which can be part of a Perl "word". The
>   definition of letters and digits is controlled by PCRE's character
>   tables, and may vary if locale-specific matching is taking place. For
>   example, in the "fr" (French) locale, some character codes greater
>   than 128 are used for accented letters, and these are matched by \w.